# Clojure - Reflection Warning with primitive array .length

Tags: clojure, primitive

I'm having some trouble trying to use instance methods on a java float array in clojure. Specifically, the following code gives a reflection warning on the call to `.length`

```
(defn make-matrix
  ([^floats fs]
   (let [len-fs (.length fs)]
     (cond (>= len-fs 16) (Matrix4. fs)
           (>= len-fs 9)  (Matrix3. fs)
           :else (throw (IllegalArgumentException. (str "Array must have at least 9 elements (found" len-fs ")")))))))
```

By my understanding, the type-hint should eliminate the need for reflection to resolve the call to `.length`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Arrays on the JVM are not quite like regular objects and their lengths are not obtained through a field lookup, but rather through a specialized opcode `arraylength`. Java's `array.length` notation is just syntactic sugar that compiles down to this opcode. Therefore, `(.length fs)` will simply fail at runtime, because `fs` will be found to have neither a `length` method nor a `length` field (assuming it is in a fact an array).

Thus, you should use the `clojure.core/alength` function:

```
(alength fs)
```

Without a type hint, this will result in a reflective call; with a type hint, it will be a direct call to a static method returning `fs.length` (in Java notation).

Answer (score 3):

Primitive arrays are a somewhat special case in the JVM, a proof of this is that there's a bytecode instruction for getting the length of them: [arraylength](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings). So the reason why Clojure is showing a reflection warning is because the class for arrays of floats `[F` does not declare a field with the name `length`, so when it tries to get it ([here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L1091)) the field is not there.

You can check it yourself doing the following:

```
(-> (float-array [1])
  class
  (.getField "length"))
```